# How to pass variables to Bazel target build?

Tags: environment-variables, bazel

I am trying to build a Docker image with this code:

```
container_image(
    name = "docker_image",
    base = "@java_base//image",
    files = [":executable_deploy.jar"],
    cmd = ["java", "-jar", "executable_deploy.jar"],
    env = { "VERSION" : "$(VERSION)" }
)
```

I want to pass a variable to the target built so it can be replaced in $(VERSION). Is this possible?

I have tried with `VERSION=1.0.0 bazel build :docker_image`, but I get an error:

> $(VERSION) not defined.

How can I pass that variable?

[According docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#container_image-1):

> The values of this field (env) support make variables (e.g., $(FOO)) and
>   stamp variables; keys support make variables as well.
>    But I don't understand exactly what that means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those variables can be set via the [`--define`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--define) flag.

There is a section on the rules_docker page about [stamping](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#stamping) which covers this.

Essentially you can do something like:
`bazel build --define=VERSION=1.0.0 //:docker_image`

It is also possible to source these key / value pairs from the `stable-status.txt` and `volatile-status.txt` files. The [user manual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--workspace_status_command) page for bazel shows how to use these files, and the use of the [`--workspace_status_command`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag) to populate them.

For setting defaults, you could use a [`.bazelrc`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#bazelrc) file, with something like the following as the contents:

```
build --define=VERSION=0.0.0-PLACEHOLDER
```

The flags passed on the command line will take precedence over those in the .bazelrc file.

It's worth mentioning, that changing `define` values will cause bazel to analyze everything again, which depending on the graph may take some time, but only affected actions will be executed.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Is it possible to provide a default value for a variable when --define is not used?

Comment: Updated the answer to include a way to set defaults, as well as a note regarding incrementality with changing `define` values

Comment: --action_env is also available 
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--action_env

Comment: Do you have an example of how the contents of `*-status.txt` can eventually be passed in to `container_image`'s `env` parameter? Because it looks like normal BUILD rules **cannot** read files: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/13300