# How to pass docker image tag from bazel command line

Tags: bazel

Is there possible to pass docker image tag from command line, like:

```
bazel run :myimage_push --tag=foo_tag
```

so that the effect will be equivalent to

```
container_push(
  name = "myimage_push",
  format = "Docker",
  image = ":myimage",
  registry = "some.registry",
  repository = "some/repository",
  tag = "foo_tag",
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [pass variables to bazel target build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61045101/6162120) like this:

```
bazel run --define=TAG=foo_tag :myimage_push
```

Just replace `tag = "foo_tag",` with `tag = "$(TAG)",` in your BUILD file.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively of what @piarston said, you can user is to use [stamping](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#stamping)

**Method 1:**

```
container_push(
  name = "myimage_push",
  format = "Docker",
  image = ":myimage",
  registry = "some.registry",
  repository = "some/repository",
  tag = "{TAG}",
)
```

then run

```
bazel push :myimage_push --workspace_status_command="echo TAG 1.0.0"
```

**Method 2:**

You can also put `stamp` vars in a bash script. Example

```
cat <<EOF
# This can be overridden by users if they "export VAR2_OVERRIDE"
# VAR2 ${VAR2_OVERRIDE:-default-value2}
TAG ${TAG_OVERRIDE:-1.0.0}
# more variables
EOF%
```

then run

```
bazel push :myimage_push --workspace_status_command="bash vars.sh"
```